# Compare two Lists of different object types based on matching property in java 8

Tags: java, list, java-stream, compare

I have two Lists of type:

```
class User {
    Long userId;
    String userName;
    Long workflowStatusId;
}

class WorkflowStatus {
    Long workflowStatusId;
    String workflowStatusName;
    Long userId;
}
```

Each user object have workflowStatusId. Similarly, each WorkflowStatus have userId associated with them.
I am saving `User`s first, which is giving me `List<User> users` where `workflowStatusId` is set as null for each object. Now for each of these user in users, I am making new entries in `WorkflowStatus` which is giving me `List<WorkflowStatus> workflowStatuses`. Now I want to set these newly inserted `workflowStatusId` in my previously saved `User` object, so I am trying to match `userId` property in both and want to set this `workflowStatusId` once that match is found. I am trying to do something like:

```
List<User> filteredList = users
                                            .stream()
                                             .filter(user -> workflowStatuses
                                                                .stream()
                                                                .allMatch(user.getUserId().equals(workflowStatus.getUserId())))
                                                                .map(how to set workflowStatusId in user? can i do something like user->user.setWorkflowStatusId((workflowStatus.getWorkflowStatusId)))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Trying to find some solution, if it is possible to do using `Java 8 streams`. What is the better way to Compare two Lists of different object types based on some common property in java 8?

Comment: Is this a typo `user.getUserId().equals(workflowStatus.getWorkflowStatusId))` or is it correct in your case to compare `userId` and `workflowStatusId` ?

Comment: @eritrean it is typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to have side effects like setting of properties in the middle of a Stream.  A better solution is to just create a Map of your User instances:

```
Map<Long, User> usersById =
    users.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getUserId, u -> u));
```

Now you can simply loop through your WorkflowStatus objects:

```
for (WorkflowStatus status : workflowStatuses) {
    Long userId = status.getUserId();
    Long statusId = status.getWorkflowStatusId();
    usersById.get(userId).setWorkflowStatusId(statusId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<User> filteredList = users.stream().filter(user -> workflowStatuses
                                                            .stream()
                                                            .allMatch(user.getUserId().equals(workflowStatus.getWorkflowStatusId)))
                                                            .map(how to set workflowStatusId in user? can i do something like user->user.setWorkflowStatusId((workflowStatus.getWorkflowStatusId)))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

On this generate the lamba exprestion loop on java 8

```
workflowStatus.foreach( data ) -> { user.setworkflowStatusId(data.getWorkflowStatusId);user.setuserId(data.getuserId);}
```

Or simple replace below

```
<User> filteredList = users.stream().filter(user -> workflowStatuses
                                                        .stream()
                                                        .allMatch(user.getUserId().equals(workflowStatus.getWorkflowStatusId)))
                                                        .map(workflowStatus.foreach( data ) -> { user.setworkflowStatusId(data.getWorkflowStatusId);user.setuserId(data.getuserId)})
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```